# How to exclude a property from a referenced schema?

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi, data-modeling

I have an endpoint to create an address and one to update it. Describing this in an OpenAPI spec I'd like to use a component for the address so that I don't have to specify the address twice. Now the problem is, that the address object used for updating should include a property "id", but the one used for creating doesn't.

So basically, I'm looking for a way to describe the full address (incl. the id property) in the components section and then reference to the create endpoint, but excluding the "id" property there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend another type using the `allOf` keyword, [as documented here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/)

In the example below, `creationType` has only a `name` property, but `updateType` has all the properties of `creationType` as well as an `id` property.

Example:

```
components:
  schemas:
    creationType:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
    updateType:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/creationType'
      - type: object
        required:
        - id
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
```

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this using the `readOnly` keyword, which provides a standardized method to achieve the desired outcome.

> You can use the `readOnly` and writeOnly keywords to mark specific properties as read-only or write-only. This is useful, for example, when `GET` returns more properties than used in `POST` – you can use the same schema in both `GET` and `POST` and mark the extra properties as readOnly. `readOnly` properties are included in responses but not in requests, and `writeOnly` properties may be sent in requests but not in responses.

example:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
    id:
        # Returned by GET, not used in POST/PUT/PATCH
        type: integer
        readOnly: true
    username:
        type: string
    password:
        # Used in POST/PUT/PATCH, not returned by GET
        type: string
        writeOnly: true
```

> If a `readOnly` or `writeOnly` property is included in the required list, required affects just the relevant scope – responses only or requests only. That is, read-only required properties apply to responses only, and write-only required properties – to requests only.

See documentation: [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#readonly-writeonly)

#### Petstore example:

Notice that we use the same model for both the payload and response. However, the `id` property is excluded from the payload due to its `readOnly` attribute being set to `true`.

```yaml
...
        Pet:
            required:
                - name
                - photoUrls
            type: object
            properties:
                id:
                    type: integer
                    format: int64
                    example: 10
                    readOnly: true
...
```

[image]

[image]